# scrollintoView not taking component to the top of the page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Below is the home.vue component which has service and legal two other components. In the mounted() I have if *id* is present? then scrollinto view the legal section. The issue I am facing here is it does scroll a little but doesnt scroll legal section to the top of the page. Attached is the image. Please help me find where I am going wrong

[image: issue]

home.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Service id="service"></Service>
    <br />
    <hr>
    <Legal id="legal"></Legal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Service from 'views/home/service.vue';
import Legal from 'views/legal.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    Service,
    Legal,
  },
  props: ['id'],
  mounted() {
    // this.id == 'legal'
    if (this.id) {
      this.$nextTick(()=> window.document.getElementById('legal').scrollIntoView());
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the full page looks like, but just to clarify, is it only scrolling it to the top of the Legal component?

Comment: @nbixler yes thats right it is just scrolling it to the top of Legal Component and not bringing legal component to the top of the page.

Comment: You may have considered this already, but can you just swap the Service and Legal components within the Home.vue template?  Does that get you the effect you're looking for?  

Alternatively, can you include your current css?  You may want to attach a class to Legal that gives it absolute positioning (or stickied to the top of the page, etc).

Comment: @nbixler I can't switch the two components.

Comment: @nbixler can you explain little more the alternative part. Maybe I can try that.

Comment: I'd need to see more of your css, but if you set margin-top: negative foo px, or set the position to absolute and placed it where you want, it may scroll into view to the point where you want it. (But I'm not sure what else it might bump against)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `querySelector`.

```
mounted(){
    if(this.id){
      const el = this.$el.querySelector("#service");
      if (el) {
        el.scrollIntoView();
      }
    }
  }
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/bGrYYZP

Comment: const el = this.$el.querySelector("#legal") returns undefined